# The system cannot find the path specified. - Error when trying to run flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal, path

I'm trying to set up flutter to use with Visual Studio Code, and have added all the relevant paths to the environment variables (as far as I know).

When trying to run flutter doctor the terminal just shows:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

And nothing else, just waits for a new input.

I've added paths to Android Studio SDK, and flutter\bin, and have also added C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32, as somebody advised on here to get to the stage I'm at now.

Can anybody advise a solution? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks